# Referencing js classes from other files

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am learning react and I am using the es6 class syntax (`class ...` instead of `function.prototype`). For the most part, all of my front end code can go into a single file per page so I was not intending to use a js bundler to separate all of my component classes into different files.

The problem is that I do have a couple of components that I would like to reuse between a few pages. I assumed that if I put those in a separate file and simply included both the main script and the component script in the html that the main script could reference the classes in the component script via global scope but that doesn't seem to be the case based on this error.

You can see the code below but I'm wondering if there is some way to reference classes in other files without bundling. I know you can do it with the older prototype style classes.

At the end of the html body in this order:

```
<script src="players/player_search.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="players/players.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

In player_search.js:

```
class PlayerSearch extends React.Component{...}
```

In players.js:

```
class LeaderboardPage extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <PlayerSearch/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad practice as you are polluting the global scope.

If you really have to, you could always put them under `window` scope.

```
class PlayerSearch {}
window.PlayerSearch = PlayerSearch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your html you need to make a container to hold your react components.

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Then you would usually have an index page to initialize react-dom and render your component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'; // or whatever you want

ReactDOM.render( <App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

I would recommend using create-react-app if possible

Comment: This answer is the complete opposite from what I was asking about. I was asking if there is some way to do it without bundling and hence without import statements as a whole.